# Use scanner on a HP8180 with obsolete ink cartridges

Tags: scanning

I use a PhotoSmart 8180 mainly for scanning. The ink cartridges are full, but 2 years old. I can't scan, for the printer asks me to change the ink cartridges. A phone call to Tech Support at HP France confirmed this fact. Your scanner is under the Damocles' sword of programmed obsolescence of ink cartridges...

I just would like to know:

- If here is a trick to bypass or twitch this blackmail integrated system (If you don't buy ink, you shall not scan)
- If there is a trick to use only the black ink for I don't care with color, and I'm tired to throw full color cartridges ONLY because of programmed obsolescence.

Answer (score 0):

You have to fool your printer that you have new cartridges.
Sometimes information is stored on the PC, sometimes in the printer.

Try this:

> 1. There's a "secret" menu which you enter by pressing the "<" (left) button and the "Settings" button at the same time.
> 2. You move through the menu with <, >, X and OK buttons.
> 3. Enter the menu, press OK (something like "Support R0631M" should appear).
> 4. Scroll to "System configuration menu" and choose "hardware failure status", press OK, and "Press OK to clear". You will be prompted that
>      the status were cleared and the printer may buzz for a while, possibly
>      adjusting the inks or something.

I have found this on some forums...